# Specflow - How to pass parameter in Scenario outline description

Tags: specflow

Please can you help me in providing an solution on how to pass parameter in Scenario outline description of Spec Flow? Please see below for an example:

```
Scenario Outline : Testing **<Application>**
    Given I navigate to <Application>
    Then I should see Home page

    Examples:
    | Application |
    | Test        |
    | Test1       |
```

I know this is possible in Cucumber but don't know the way to do it in Specflow. Appreciate your response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any idea, how to achieve this in watir/cucumber?

Answer (score 3):

There is no benefit in doing this. Just write a generic scenario title that explains the use case:

```
Scenario Outline: Navigating to the home page
    Given I navigate to <Application>
    Then I should see Home page

Examples:
    | Application    |
    | Stack Overflow |
    | Math Overflow  |
```

SpecFlow will append the the test name with data from the first column of your examples table:

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Test Explorer panel showing test names]